# Minimum cost cycle on complete graph

Tags: path-finding, graph-traversal

I have a [complete graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) with undirected, weighted edges and need to find the lowest cost [cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_%28graph_theory%29) through a subset of the graph nodes. Unlike in [Travelling Salesman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), *any* node can be visited *more than once* and *not all* nodes need to be visited, and by cost I mean the path should have the smallest sum of traversed edge weights.

For example, here is a graph in [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) form:

```
  a b c d
a 0 3 4 5
b 3 0 2 4
c 4 2 0 1
d 5 4 1 0
```

where the weight of each edge is used for each element. Cycles starting and ending at `a` and including `[b,d]` would look like

```
[a,b,d,a] -> 3+4+5 = 12
[a,b,d,b,a] -> 3+4+4+3 = 14
[a,b,c,d,c,a] -> 3+2+1+1+4 = 11
```

Is there an optimal algorithm for this, or a really good heuristic one?

Comment: Can you say more about the subset of the complete graph that has to be traversed? Would the subset of nodes be specified for each case, e.g. something like "given a complete graph of nodes [a, b, c, d, e, f, g] with specified edge weights, find the minimum cost cycle through the subset [a, b, d, f] that may re-visit nodes"? If so, how would that be different from the problem "given a complete graph of nodes [a, b, d, f] find the minimum cost cycle that may re-visit nodes"? Alternatively, could a solution that finds a cycle of the subset include visiting nodes that are not in the subset?

Comment: Yes, the nodes outside the subset must be considered even though the intervening nodes aren't necessary to the cycle. Here is why:
Consider that the edges between each node in the subset may be _more_ expensive than "short cut" edges on a node outside the subset.
So if I have a set `[a,b,c]` and only need to travel from `a` to `b`, if the edge from `a->b` has weight 10, `a->c` has weight 2, and `c->b` has weight 2, then clearly any algorithm must consider `c` as it happens to be part of the better path.
There could be multiple best paths for a given graph with the same cost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cycles starting and ending at `a` and including `[b,d]` simply means cycle must visit nodes a,b,d. `[a,b,d,a] = [b,d,a,b]` (cycles right). Your problem is called k-TSP. See [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/14079/shortest-cycle-with-a-specific-number-of-vertices). But this is very hard to implement and may not be what you are looking for.

So I will just give you a simpler way. First construct shortest cycle that passes through just these nodes. Then replace each edge with smallest path between then the two nodes. I think it is reasonable, I leave out optimality. Here are the steps :

- V=nodes E=edges and M=must-visit nodes.
- Create cycle `C` by running [TSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) on M (without using other nodes), adding extra edge to make the cycle.
- Now using all nodes V. For each edge `uv` in the the `C`, do:
- Find shortest path `w` between `u` and `v` using [Dijsktra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) (should be no negative cycle in graph).
- Replace `uv` with `w`.

Comment: Oh excellent, I think I can tackle this now! Very helpful, thank you!